# execute SQL with output parameter (with IF condition)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 1

WHILE ((SELECT count(*) from ##tmp_tname_pkey_map) >= @counter-1) 
BEGIN

DECLARE @table varchar(250);
DECLARE @primarykey varchar(250);
  SELECT @table =  TABLE_NAME from ##tmp_tname_pkey_map where INDEX_ID = @counter;
  SELECT @primarykey =  PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN from ##tmp_tname_pkey_map where INDEX_ID = @counter;

            DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
            DECLARE @maxVal BIGINT; 
            SET @query = 'SELECT @maxVal = max(' + @primarykey + ') from ' + @table;

            EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@maxVal INT out', @maxVal out
```

The Code above is part of a stored procedure that I use to get the list of all tables and their primary keys (mostly INTEGERS except one table) and get their maximum value.

This works fine for the tables that contain INT values for the variable @primarykey.

My question is if there is a way to include a condition in/before the query to check for INT type before the query is executed with errors.

Comment: When you populate your temp table listing indexes, possibly also set the type, then have two possible statements, one where you do for ints and one for whatever the other type is.

Comment: @SqlZim - The above code is part of a stored procedure, that creates a table that contains Tablename, PrimaryKey, Max value of primaryKey for each table in the schema. It fails when I query for max (primary key) when the primary key is not of int/bigint type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be interested to know what you would use this sort of thing for, what value does this operation provide?

---

General notes:

- Declare your variables outside of your loop, and reset them inside your loop.
- Use `sysname` for names of system objects for forward (and backward) compatibility in your scripts.
- You can set multiple variables with a single `select`.
- Use `quotename()` around object names that might have spaces or other characters that require wrapping in square brackets for dynamic sql.
- You could probably use a local temporary table instead of a global temporary table.
- You could add a column for `datatype` and include it in the generation of `##tmp_tname_pkey_map` to streamline this process.

```
declare @table sysname, @primarykey sysname, @primarykey_datatype sysname;
declare @query nvarchar(max);
declare @maxVal bigint; 

declare @count int = (select count(*) from ##tmp_tname_pkey_map);
declare @i int = 1;

while (@i <= @count) 
begin;
  /* reset variables */
  select 
    @table = null
  , @primarykey = null
  , @primarykey_datatype = null
  , @query = null
  , @maxVal = null;

  /* get variable values from temp table */
  select 
      @table = table_name
    , @primarykey = primary_key_column  
    , @query = 'select @maxVal = max(' + quotename(primary_key_column) 
             + ') from ' + quotename(table_name)+';';
  from ##tmp_tname_pkey_map 
  where index_id = @i;

  /* using system catalog views to get the datatype of a column */
  select @primarykey_datatype = y.name
  from sys.tables t 
    inner join sys.columns c 
      on t.object_id = c.object_id
    inner join sys.types y
      on c.user_type_id = y.user_type_id
    where t.name = @table
      and c.name = @primarykey;

  /* check primary key data type, set @query null if not integer based */
  if @primarykey_datatype not in ('tinyint', 'smallint', 'int', 'bigint')
  begin;
    set @query = null;
    print @table +' primary key '+@primarykey+' datatype is: '+@primarykey_datatype;
  end;

  /* execute @query if it is not null */
  if @query is not null
  begin;
  exec sp_executesql @query, N'@maxVal int output', @maxVal out;
  end;

  /* increment loop counter @i */
  set @i = @i + 1;
end;
```

Comment: The above code is part of a stored procedure, that creates a table that contains Tablename, PrimaryKey, Max value of primaryKey for each table in the schema. It fails when I query for max (primary key) when the primary key is not of int/bigint type.

Thanks for your code above, I am able to get the data type for the columns now. appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your code but it looks like you're using a global temp table.  Maybe you should filter out records first using the ISNUMERIC function.